# MySQL JOIN query giving different results on different databases

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running an query on my database locally installed on my machine and getting a result different to one when ran on my AWS RDS database.
I am running:

```
SELECT SUM(Hours) AS 'TotalHours', Username, Name, Project_Name, Project_Ref, (37.5-SUM(Hours)) AS 'Missing'  
FROM bookings b 
JOIN projects p ON b.Project_ID=p.Project_ID 
RIGHT JOIN users u ON b.User_ID=u.User_ID   
WHERE  ((Date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30') OR Date IS NULL) 
GROUP BY u.User_ID
```

When ran on local I get back every entry from the users table, even if they haven't made a booking on the bookings table.

When ran on my server database I only get back users who have made a booking, not ever entry like expected when doing a right join.

Comment: So is your RDS also MySQL?

Comment: Are you sure to use the same database version? Check for both database ..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`, and put the `Date` criteria in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(Hours) AS 'TotalHours', Username, Name, Project_Name, Project_Ref, (37.5-SUM(Hours)) AS 'Missing'  
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN bookings AS b ON b.User_ID = u.User_ID AND b.DATE BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30'
LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON b.Project_ID=p.Project_ID
```

I suspect the problem is related to the `INNER JOIN` with `projects` in between the `users` and `bookings` table.